# Adding resources to project from existing files

Tags: c#, xml, console-application, resx

Simple and plain question as this is the first time for me working with resources. To my console application/C# I have an xml file that contains some data, then I chose to add this xml file as a resource to my project, the question is, if I once need to change the data in the xml file, does the resource file update accordingly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, files added as resource stay in they original format and can be changed via normal editors for that file format. Obviously you will need to recompile project to see the change in resources.

Note that by default source files will be copied into project (so you need to modify copy in the project folder), but you can explicitly add "as link" to refer to some other file on your local disk.